# How to use Spring Batch HibernateItemWriter to persist mapped entities?

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-batch

I'm trying to write a spring batch job to parse a nested XML and persist the data using Hibernate to multiple tables. I was able unmarshall the xml using StaxEventItemReader. I tried persisting the data using HibernateItemWriter but this is saving only the top level entity 'Shipment', but not the mapped entity 'Party'.

This is my xml

```
<Shipment>
<TransactionId>000551070008555</TransactionId>
<TransactionSetPurpose>Replace</TransactionSetPurpose>
<TransactionType>Customer</TransactionType>
<Parties>
 <Party>
   <PartyType>Account</PartyType>
   <PartyCode>933334</PartyCode>
   <Name>AT HOME</Name>
 </Party>
 <Party>
   <PartyType>Shipper</PartyType>
   <PartyCode>CVASIH</PartyCode>
   <Name>CV.WIDHI ASIH BALI EXPORT</Name>
 </Party>
<Parties>
</Shipment>
```

My processor class

```
public class ShipmentItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Shipment, 
Shipment> {

@Override
public Shipment process(Shipment result) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Processing result :"+result);

    Set<Party> partySet = new HashSet<Party>();
    partySet.addAll(result.getParties().getParty());
    result.setPartySet(partySet);

    return result;
}
}
```

How can I return my Party Set along with Shipment to HibernateItemWriter from the processor?

Shipment

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Shipment")
@Entity
public class Shipment{

protected String transactionId;
protected String transactionSetPurpose;
protected String transactionType;
@Id
protected String fileNumber;
@Transient
protected Parties parties;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "shipment")
private Set<Party> partySet = new HashSet<Party>(0); 

--getters and setters

}
```

Party

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "Party")
public class Party {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected int id;
protected String partyType;
protected String partyCode;
protected String name;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fileNumber", nullable = false)
protected Shipment shipment;
--getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Can you share how those two are mapped?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael. Edited my question with the mapping.